# open new window using window.open by "Post" parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, window

i want to open a new window using window.open(). but the issue is i don't want to show the URL to user, so i have to use POST URL for this. but window.open() function opens the new window and shows the URL in URL bar. i have to hide the URL.

here is the Example :

```
window.open(URL,"_blank",'status=0,toolbar=0,resizable=0,menubar=0,titlebar=0,width=1180,height=770');
```

Comment: `<form method="post" action="/yourserver" target="_blank">`

Comment: no dude. i'm using Jquery to open new window. not the Form tag. please check example.

Comment: If `jQuery` then use [`$.post()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/), and open your window at the end.

Comment: It is an important security feature, as you can never be sure what popped that extra window. Could be a malicious piece of code that tries to steal your login details for example. By showing the address bar, users can verify what exactly they're looking at and whether their connection is secure. It's up to the browser how it displays your content and what customisations you can do. If you want full control over the UI, use other technologies and develop a desktop/mobile app instead of a web app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't hide address bar in modern browser.

**location=no** paramter will not working.
See the MDN document.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open

> In Firefox 3, **dom.disable_window_open_feature.location** now defaults to
>   true, forcing the presence of the Location Bar much like in IE7.

**location** parameter is also always enabled (means location=yes) in Google Chrome.

---

But you can assign a fake URL:

```
var win = window.open('/path/page.htm');
win.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    win.history.replaceState(null, null, '/fake.htm');   // must be same domain (or ignore domain)
});
```